# printing and deleting data from binary tree, c++

Tags: c++11, binary-tree

Good evening,
I am struggling with printing my binary tree

```
#ifndef TREE_H_INCLUDED
#define TREE_H_INCLUDED

#include "qt.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Tree{
    Node<T> *root;
    void insertIntoTree(T &d, Node<T> *&r);
    void printTree(Node<T> *r);
    void deleteTree(Node<T> *&r);
    Node<T>* findInTree(T &d, Node<T> *r, Node<T> *&parent);
    void deleteLeaf(Node<T> *p, Node<T> *q);
    void deleteInBranch(Node<T> *p, Node<T> *g);
public:
    Tree() : root(nullptr){}
    ~Tree(){
        clean();
    }
    bool find(T d){
        Node<T> *dummy=nullptr;
        return findInTree(d, root, dummy);
    };
    void clean(){
        deleteTree(root);}
    void insert(T d){
         insertIntoTree(d, root);}
    void print(){
        printTree(root);
    }
    bool deleteNode(T d);
};

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::insertIntoTree(T &d, Node<T> *&r){
    if(!r){
        r = new Node<T>(d);
        return;
    }
    if(r->getData()<d){
        insertIntoTree(d, r->right);
    }
    else{
        insertIntoTree(d, r->left);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::printTree(Node<T> *r){
    if(r){
        printTree(r->left);
        r->print();
        printTree(r->right);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::deleteTree(Node<T> *&r){
    if(r){
        deleteTree(r->left);
        deleteTree(r->right);
        delete r;
        r = nullptr;
    }
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>* Tree<T>::findInTree(T &d, Node<T> *r, Node<T> *&parent){
    if(!r){
        return nullptr;
    }
    if(r->getData()==d){
        return r;
    }
    parent = r;
    if(r->getData()<d){
        return findInTree(d, r->right, parent);
     }
    else{
        return findInTree(d, r->right, parent);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::deleteLeaf(Node<T> *p, Node<T> *q){
    if(p == root){
        root = nullptr;
    }
    else{
        if(p->right == q)
            q->right = nullptr;
        else
            q->left = nullptr;
    }
    delete p;
}

template<typename T>
void Tree<T>::deleteInBranch(Node<T> *p, Node<T> *q){
    Node<T> *s = (p->left ? p->left : p->right);
    if(p == root){
        root = s;
    }else{
        if(q->left == p){
            q->left = s;
        }
        else{
            q->right = s;
        }
    }
    delete p;
}

template<typename T>
bool Tree<T>::deleteNode(T d){
   Node<T> *p, *q = nullptr;
   p = findInTree(d, root, q);
   if(!p){
       return false;
   }
   if(!p->left && !p->right){
        deleteLeaf(p, q);
   } else if(!p->left || !p->right){
       deleteInBranch(p, q);
   } else{
       Node<T> *r = p->left; 
       q = p;
       while(r->right){
           q = r;
           r = r->right;
       }
       p->setData(r->getData());
       if(r->left){
           deleteInBranch(r, q);
       } else{
           deleteLeaf(r, q);
       }
   }
   return true;
}

#endif // TREE_H_INCLUDED
```

qt.h

```
#ifndef QT_H_INCLUDED
#define QT_H_INCLUDED

#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
class Node{
    T data;
    Node<T> *left;
    Node<T> *right;
public:
    Node(T d) : data(d), left(nullptr), right(nullptr){}
    void print(){
        std::cout << data << std::endl;}
    T getData()const {
        return data;
        }
    void setData(const T &value){
        data = value;
        }
    template<typename X> friend class Tree;
};

#endif // QT_H_INCLUDED
```

and unfortunately I have to post main.cpp, too

```
#include <iostream>
#include "qt.h"
#include "tree.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Tree<int> t;
    t.insert(42);
    t.insert(26);
    t.insert(10);
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(53);
    t.insert(9);
    t.insert(38);
    if(t.find(42)){
        cout << "nalezeno" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "nenalezeno" << endl;
    if(t.deleteNode(42)){
        cout << "smazano" << endl;
    }
    t.print();
     return 0;
}
```

The problem is, when I run it, it works, when I add only 6 number, when I add the seventh (38), the program falls, no error, no warning. I really cannot find the problem, I think, that it is probably in the deleting of (42), not the printing, but I cannot find the reason.
Thank you for helping

Comment: If the program crashes, you should use the debugger to determine crash location. For that open the "call stack" and navigate down until you find one of your functions. Depending on the debugger you can usually just double-click your function and it will show you the crash location in your code.

Comment: still dont know how to do that, but at least I found the mistake, thank you for your answer :)